# how to get two separate error results in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

trying to make basic user registration script with PDO, when user and email exists i get single error message (user or email already exists), what im trying to get separate output for user and email errors. Also any other suggestions about this script much appreciated

```
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//Validating ???


$statement  = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users 
    WHERE username = :username AND email = :email");
$statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
$statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
$statement->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':email' => $email));

    while ($row = $statement ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $result = $row["count"];
        }
        if ($result > 0) {
            echo "That usernam or email is already taken";

            }
        else {
            $sql = ("INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
            $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindValue(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindValue(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute(array("$username", "$email", "$password"));
            echo "New record created successfully";
            }
}
```

Comment: `VALUES(?, ?, ?)` will not work with named placeholders and you should have gotten an error about that.

Comment: `SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=?` if two rows found - both options taken, if one - check if email, else its username

Comment: RTMs http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php  --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: thanks for answers, ill check my insert query too, so far it worked but not sure there anything else wrong

Comment: I'm going to mention a security thing here, you should be cautious about letting someone through a simple web request ping your server for usernames and emails. I would rate limit and and maybe even use action request tokens for CRSF.

Comment: thanks for reminding me, i still need to learn allot till i get to security issues but ill do my best

Comment: You can simply execute the INSERT without the Select. If the INSERT fails then the data already exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do this:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(IF (username IS NOT NULL AND username != '', 1, NULL)) AS username_taken
 , COUNT(IF (email IS NOT NULL AND email != '', 1, NULL)) AS email_taken
FROM users 
WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER(TRIM(:username))
OR LOWER(email) = LOWER(TRIM(:email))
```

Note, the reason I'm using `COUNT()` here is to aggregate if there are two result rows. `COUNT()` ignores `NULL`, so this will compress two rows to one and return `1` or `0` (from `COUNT()`), or simply provide `1` for both columns if it's the same row.

Also, as @Fred -ii- points out, you've got the wrong PDO method call for the type of binding you're doing later on. So:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO users (
   username, email, password
) VALUES (
   TRIM(:username), TRIM(:email), :password
)
";

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

$statement->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: thanks allot Jared, one more question, how do i setup loop and get results for your query you posted (possible get seperate result for email and username), i tried tweaking my query but didnt work

Comment: You don't need a loop with this query.

Comment: For the password you're saving, I would recommend to you http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing, which please read; security is hard and you need to do it right. I would also recommend using at least `TRIM()` and might as well use `LOWER()`, in your insert for these usernames and emails (but NOT the password!). This is to make the data you're storing consistent, and neither extraneous edge whitespace nor varying character casing matters. Look at the `SELECT` in my answer for how I used these together.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $statement->fetchColumn();
$email = $statement->fetchColumn(1);

if ($username != null) {
    echo "Username already taken";
}
elseif ($email != null) {
    echo "Email already taken";
}
else{
    //Insert entry into DB
}
```

OR

```
if ($row["username"] != null) {
   echo "Username already taken";
}
elseif ($row["email"] != null) {
    echo "Email already taken";
}
else{
    //Insert entry into DB
}
```

Also, your query needs to be changed to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email
```

Because with your current query, you cannot check both username and email address at the same time.

Comment: As it stands, because of the `AND`, a row would have to have both, so the query must be changed too.

Comment: Well, that partially worked, You should remove the `COUNT()` now, and what if it's on two different rows?

Answer (score -2):

In order to get different error messages, queries must be seperated.

1. Check for username (if found, throw error)
2. If not found, check for email (if found, throw error)
3. If not found, insert user data

Comment: already got another version with two queries, but wasnt sure if i can make everything into single query